# Round boxes hierarchy

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could you give me a hand with this one? I don't l know how to draw it :(

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
forked edges,
for tree={draw,align=center,edge={-latex},fill=white,blur shadow}
[Recommendation\\ Systems
 [1.1]
 [1.2
  [1.2.1
   [1.2.1.1]
   [1.2.1.2]
  ]
  [1.2.2
   [1.2.2.1]
   [1.2.2.2]
   [1.2.2.3]
  ]
 ]
 [1.3]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yor MWE is not even close to showed image. Do you like to to reproduce image? with circles and rectangles or can be all nodes rectangles with rounded corners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wee bit redesigned showed tree, do you like to draw something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14159]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    draw, rounded corners, inner sep=2pt,
    align=center,
D/.append style= {fill=white, drop shadow},
% labels
EL/.style args = {#1/#2}{% shortens for (my) edge label
                         edge label={node[pos=0.66, 
                                          font=\scriptsize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
                                          inner sep=2pt, align=center, 
                                          anchor=south #1]{#2}}
                        },
% tree
    l sep=12mm,
calign=fixed edge angles,
for current and siblings={anchor=center},
if n children=1{anchor=east}{anchor=west},  
          } 
[Data, D, %circle
    [Domain, D, EL=east/Labeled%circle
        [Division, D, EL=east/Can be\\ devided%circle
            [Input space\\ Clasification, EL=east/Separable]
            [Feature space\\ Clasification, EL=west/Unseparable]
        ]
        [Regresion, EL=west/Cannot be\\ devided
        ]
    ]
    [Clustering, EL=west/Not\\ Labeled]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```